# HTTP 500 Error in PHP script

Tags: php, mysqli

i'm having an 500 error with my register.php file.
I have no clue why...
I tried some php validator website but they don't help me alot. xd

Here is the code:

register.php:

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
// If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
            $premium = "false";
            $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?: $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']?: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $countrycodeget = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
            $countrycode = $countrycodeget->country;
            $active = "1"
            $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email, premium, ip, countrycode, active) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email',         '$premium', '$ip', '$countrycode', '$active')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        if ($result) {
            $smsg = "Your account has been created.";
        } else {
            $fmsg ="An error occured, please try again later.";
        }
    }
?>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
if (!$connection){
die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'test');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
```

Comment: What is this 500 Error? Is there something in the Apache logs?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_error",true); add this tow line at top of you register.php

Comment: @bharatsavani, it would be better if he did that in the php.ini or in .htaccess file. Since the PHP file has a syntax error and won't execute, placing *anything* in there will be of little help.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries. You need to hash the user's password. This is a very insecure application.

Comment: I know it is insecure, it's only a test ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *do* have at least one syntax error here:

```
 $active = "1"
```

There's no semicolon at the end of the line.

But next time, you should specify:

- the exact text of the 500 error you're getting (in this case it might have been "Syntax error at line..." which would have be an enormous help)
- the error in the php_error log, or in the Apache error log, if available

In a pinch, you can get your PHP file analyzed by the command line PHP without involving any validator site:

```
php -l name/of/your/file.php
```

## Debugging

So you got:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user     'admin'@'localhost' to database 'account' in /dir/account/connect.php on line 2 

PHP Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /dir/account/connect.php on line 4
```

The second warning is due to the fact that you passed `$connection` without checking it to be a valid resource. So:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(...);
if (!is_resource($connection)) {
    die("Connection error"); // And you cannot use $connection.
}
```

The first warning is from MySQL:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user     'admin'@'localhost' to database 'account' in /dir/
```

Apparently the user admin has no access rights to the account database.

You need an administrator account to log onto MySQL server, and when you're there:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON account.* TO 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The first command grants access, and the second command makes it stick. Notice the 'localhost': that's where the server believes that your connection comes from.

You strongly want to give the access host to the **exact same host** MySQL told you it saw you come from. Even if you believe that it makes no difference, it does (or it might do, and why risk?).

On some systems, **even if localhost is widely regarded as a synonym for (say) 127.0.0.1**, using the wrong one will make the connection fail (this is actually truer for MySQL, where localhost is not a synonym for 127.0.0.1; but it holds for other sites, where webserver.mydomain.net resolved to x.y.z.k, and yet using x.y.z.k would not work if MySQL server saw you come from webserver.mydomain.net).

## Danger Will Robinson!

You have a further problem in your code: you take two values from the user, do not check them, *and insert them in your database*.

Suppose then that I register me a ["bobby" account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) with this password:

```
LittleBobbyTables', (SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = 'admin'), '...',...) -- '
```

Your INSERT query becomes now:

```
INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email, ...
VALUES ('bobby', 'LittleBobbyTables', (SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = 'admin'), '...',...) -- ', rest of the old code
```

The account is now created, its password is LittleBobbyTables, and its email is now **the password of the admin user**.

Hashing the password is **not a real solution** (even if some people have claimed this), because I can run the same attack on the *email* field, or even the *user* field, and recover the hashed password which, if not salted, 95% of the times will allow me to find out what the admin password is. But more to the point, if you don't protect the *login* page, I'm willing to bet that all the other pages interfacing with the database will be open even wider (on some systems, I could *lock out* the administrator and gain access for myself by sending an information query from the "contact us" page).

So you want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection), and even [this](http://www.cgisecurity.com/lib/advanced_sql_injection.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Update your register.php with the below code

```
   <?php
    require('connect.php');
    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
          $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
                $premium = "false";
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']?: $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']?: $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $countrycodeget = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
                $countrycode = $countrycodeget->country;
                $active = "1";
                $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, password, email, premium, ip, countrycode, active) VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email',         '$premium', '$ip', '$countrycode', '$active')";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
            if ($result) {
                $smsg = "Votre compte à bien été créé.";
            } else {
                $fmsg ="Une erreur s'est produite, ré-essayer plus tard.";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is missing a ; on the end:

```
 $active = "1"
```

If not that, look at your Apache/http server logs for errors.

Comment: Hello,i fixed this typo and now i get this error in error_log:

Comment: Check the username and password credentials you are using for accessing the database. Either they are wrong or they are not granted the correct permissions.